How to create initial state with Testcontainers and SQL Server
I have some tests in C# that I'm trying to migrate from a manually maintained SQL Server instance to Testcontainers.
I can set up the required databases with ExecScriptAsync but it's slow (over one hour).
When connected to the manual server instance through management studio restoring from SQL script is equally slow. But management studio allows restoring from a binary backup which takes only seconds.
How to restore a binary backup with Testcontainers?
